# List, содержащий два типа объектов

Tags: java, list

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вернуть `List`, содержащий внутри себя объекты двух классов?

Имеются объекты классов `Profession` и `Subject`

```
List<Profession> и List<Subject>
```

Как в методе вернуть их одним списком?

Comment: Либо сделать так, чтобы Profession и Subject наследовали от общего предка, либо объявлять список как List<Object>.

Comment: А зачем вам это? Вам по идее не должно такого хотеться. Может быть, вам нужно упаковать объекты попарно в класс-контейнер?

Comment: Я реализую ServiceRest , чтобы вернуть данные БД в JSON формате.@VladD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как вариант, использовать класс `Object`:

```
List<Object> objList = new ArrayList<>();
objList.addAll(professionList);
objList.addAll(subjectList);
```

Другой способ: создать класс, который инкапсулирует эти два списка:

```
class Storage {
    private List<Profession> professions;
    private List<Subject> subjects;

    public Storage(List<Profession> professions, List<Subjects> subjects) {
      ...
    }

    ...
}
```

И далее возвращаем уже `List<Storage>`.

В целом, скорее всего, ваш метод реализован некорректно, раз требуется возвращать списки двух разных классов.

Comment: Либо использовать одну из реализаций класса Pair

Comment: Ну собственно это тот же класс Storage получится, только в обобщённом виде

Comment: В Pair объекты все же будут попарно, а в вашей реализации просто два несвязанных листа.